# Windows 2008 VPS always crashes when out of disk space

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, disk-space-utilization

I am renting a Windows server 2008 dc SP2 VPS for hosting my Asp.Net projects. Now for the second time this month my VPS ran out of disk space. The first time it was a log file that got to big and yesterday it was my mistake for uploading a website without noticing the lack of space on my VPS.

Now the side effect this has is that my VPS corrupts some files when trying to write them. Last time it was Plesk that stopped working yesterday it was IIS.

So I was wondering is this normal behavior?

I called my service provider to ask if they could restore a back-up and to ask if this is normal and they ensured me it was.

I am not trying to blame them and I know it's mostly my fault for not monitoring my VPS better or for not setting better defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really sound completely normal as I've had plenty of Windows servers both bare-metal and virtual run out of system volume disk without such fatal repercussions...

...but the magnitude of issues when it happens likely depends on both the virtualization platform/underlying storage and what services/applications are running in the guest when it happens. Depending on how the files are actually being written, file corruption sounds plausible though it happening each and every time seems like bad luck or a shaky platform.

Monitoring storage is definitely vital, as you say - as running out of disk should be considered as an undefined state (ie anything including nothing could happen).

Comment: Agreed. Shouldn't crash *for sure*, but it's quite likely to.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider putting page file to a (small) partition of its own.